# Livecode error -231 starting recording

Tags: audio, audio-recording, livecode

I am trying to record audio files for an experiment that I am creating. Here is the code I am using:

```
global gSubjectID
global recordcount
on mouseUp
set the recordFormat to "wave"  -- or "wave" or "ulaw" 
set the recordCompression to "raw "
set the itemDelimiter to "/"
get the effective fileName of this stack
set the defaultFolder to item 1 to -2 of it
if not (the hilite of me) then

  if recordcount is 1 then
     put gSubjectID & space & "Question 1.wav" into fld "recordFileName"
     put fld "recordFileName" into sndName

     # make sure there's a name
     if sndName is empty then 
        exit mouseUp
     end if

     set the hilite of me to true
     record sound file sndName
     add 1 to recordcount
  end if
  end if 
end mouseUp
```

Everything seems to work, the microphone turns on and then turns off when I stop the recording with a different button.

I added the code

```
put the result
```

In order to figure out why it didn't work and I got this error:

> error -231 starting recording

This issue has not been resolved on the LiveCode forums, so I thought I would try here.

Notes:
Quicktime 7.7.7 / Livecode version 7.01 / Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

The audio recording functionality uses QuickTime. As of LiveCode 6.7 or so QuickTime is not loaded by default. You have to tell LC to use QT. Try adding this line somewhere before the `record sound file` command:

```
set the dontUseQT to false
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not resolve the issue. I am still receiving the error. Thank you for trying!